# How do you make a text keybinding in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm using unreal 4 I am new to C++ and I would like a quicker way to type in -> . Preferably I'd like to press "Control + ." to do it, How can I make a keybinding in Visual Studio 2013 to insert a certain text like -> ? Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is _gimme the codez please_ :P ... (@Cmder: Note, that you should post questions about particular problems with code you already have tried, just asking for code isn't appropriate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [command](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html) (5. Insert date and time) in [Visual Commander](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to insert any text and then assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) (commercial) automatically converts . to -> as you type if you have a pointer to an object.